# TextBox will not display the contents of a bound static generic list item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, textbox

In WPF, I have a static "Customer" object in the definition for MainWindow.xaml.cs.  This customer has a publicly accessible string Name property.  In expression blend 4, I click on the "Advanced Options" box beside the "Text" property for the TextBox that I would like to bind to the customer name.  I then click "Data Binding..." -> "Element Property" -> "window" under "scene elements" -> click the expander arrow beside "ActiveCustomer" -> then click "Name" -> "OK".  The binding is to a readonly TextBox, so One Way binding is acceptable as the default.  But when I run my app, it doesn't display the customer's name.  Any Suggestions?

```
<TextBox x:Name="AIAHNameTextBox" Height="26" Canvas.Left="90" TextWrapping="Wrap" Canvas.Top="8" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ActiveCustomer.Name, ElementName=window, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

ActiveCustomer is an instance of my Customer class:

```
namespace WPFBankingSystem
{
    public enum CustomerStatus
    { Open, Closed }
    public enum TransferType
    { CheckingToSaving, SavingToChecking }

    [Serializable]
    public class Customer
    {
        private string address;
        private Checking chkAcc;
        private string name;
        private int pin;
        private Saving savAcc;
        private string ssn;
        private AccountStatus status;
        private string tel;

        public string Address
        {
            get { return address; }
            set { address = value; }
        }
        public Checking ChkAcc
        {
            get { return chkAcc; }
            set { chkAcc = value; }
        }
        public string Name
        { get { return name; } }
        public int Pin
        {
            get { return pin; }
            set { pin = value; }
        }
        public Saving SavAcc
        {
            get { return savAcc; }
            set { savAcc = value; }
        }
        public string Ssn
        { get { return ssn; } }
        public AccountStatus Status
        {
            get { return status; }
            set { status = value; }
        }
        public string Tel
        {
            get { return tel; }
            set { tel = value; }
        }

        public void create(string Name, string Address, string TelephoneNumber, string SSN, int PIN)
        {
            this.address = Address;
            this.name = Name;
            this.pin = PIN;
            this.ssn = SSN;
            this.status = AccountStatus.Open;
            this.tel = TelephoneNumber;
        }
        public void delete()
        {
            if (this.chkAcc != null)
            { chkAcc.close(); }
            if (this.savAcc != null)
            { savAcc.close(); }
        }
        public bool hasChkAcc()
        { return (this.chkAcc != null) ? true : false; }
        public bool hasSavAcc()
        { return (this.savAcc != null) ? true : false; }
        public void show()
        { }
        public void transfer(double Amount, TransferType Type)
        {
            if(this.hasChkAcc() && this.hasSavAcc())
            {
                switch(Type)
                {
                    case TransferType.CheckingToSaving:
                        this.chkAcc.Balance -= Amount;
                        this.savAcc.Balance += Amount;
                        break;
                    case TransferType.SavingToChecking:
                        this.savAcc.Balance -= Amount;
                        this.chkAcc.Balance += Amount;
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            { throw new Exception("You do not have both a checking account and a saving account."); }
        }

        public Customer()
        { }
        ~Customer()
        { this.delete(); }
    }
}
```

Inside MainWindow.xaml.cs, the customer is defined just as a public Customer object:

```
public Customer ActiveCustomer
{ get; set; }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the definition of the `ActiveCustomer` as well.

Comment: When i said definiton of ActiveCustomer i meant the member called ActiveCustomer on the MainWindow, not the class of which it is an instance of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bind to static properties like you can to instance properties. The property `ActiveCustomer` then does not exist on the element named `window` it exists in the class `MainWindow`. You should be able to fix the binding by using a [`Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source.aspx) in conjunction with [`x:Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx):

```xml
{Binding Name, Source={x:Static local:MainWindow.ActiveCustomer}}
```

Note that `x:Static` has a very specific syntax, it does not allow an arbitrary path or the like.

Even if the binding works this is problematic though as you cannot [implement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) [`INPC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) for static properties, so if you assign a new object to `ActiveCustomer` there will be no update.

Comment: I tried resetting the property to non-static, but that failed to work as well.

Comment: Correct, although it was static before.  But this definition is after you had said that static properties are treated differently.

Comment: @JustinRoss: None of your classes appear to [implement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) [`INPC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), you might want to change that. If the property starts out as `null` you will not see the binding work unless you tell it in the setter.

Comment: No good, I just updated my customer class to implement the INPC interface.  I added NotifyPropertyChanged to each setter, and still no luck.

Comment: Any binding errors? ([Debugging Data Bindings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx))

Comment: Update: instead of implementing INPC for each field of the customer class, I implemented it for my MainWindow class and notified when I assigned the ActiveCustomer.  Now it works!  Thanks for your patience and help @H.B.

Comment: ...obivously you need to implement it there as well! It's kind of in the last sentence of my answer, well anyway, you're welcome, at least you did manage to fix it after all.